# Will a basic VPS in bandwagonhost be enough for Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: server, vps

I want to buy a [VPS](https://bandwagonhost.com/cart.php?a=confproduct&i=2) and use Ubuntu Server.

I use this for my shadowsocks service and put my up blog (may be run on python, MySQL).

Is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to be running these two services you'll easily get away with 512MB/1GB RAM even with a decent amount of traffic. The host you use will also have an impact, as many hosts limit you in terms of CPU and disk speed.